# binding in Tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python, binding, tkinter

I want my button to alternate between two strings everything its pressed. For example the first time i want the button to change the label to "Hi" then the second time you the button is pressed it says 'bye' then the third time it goes back to "Hi". Would the best solution be to use a counter ? or binding?(I've heard about it im not sure how it really works)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> texts = itertools.cycle(['Hi', 'Bye'])
>>> print next(texts)
Hi
>>> print next(texts)
Bye
>>> print next(texts)
Hi
>>> print next(texts)
Bye
```

**Edit**

A simple example:

```
import itertools
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.texts = itertools.cycle(['Hi', 'Bye'])

        self.var = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(frame, textvariable=self.var)
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button = Button(frame, text="Set Text", command=self.change_text)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)


    def change_text(self):
        self.var.set(next(self.texts))

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is my code     def clicked1(self):
   self.buttontext.set("Button")
   self.label2text = StringVar()
   self.label2 = Label(self.root, text=itertools.cycle(['Hi''Bye']), #for some reason its printing the location and not the string

Comment: @user1733141: I can't say much without seeing the whole code but I've added an example to demonstrate how you can use it.